# How to find distance only between two places with Google Map API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, widget, web-deployment

I am new to use this API.

Basically I am developing a widget that calculate freight between two places, so i just need to compute distance only there is no need of showing Map.

If any one has simple explanation please share with me.

I have gone through [this link](http://1stwebdesigner.com/distance-finder-google-maps-api/) but not able to identify which part of code i need to use for finding distance only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Geometry` `computeDistanceBetween()`

```
var placeA = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.873, 151.13);
var placeB = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.05);

console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(placeA, placeB));
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#SphericalGeometry

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.